# How to update in Indicator in StatusBar before calling a AfxMessageBox

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc

MDI or SDI App. How can we right immediately update an Indicator in Statusbar before call a MessageBox?
The MessageBox, stops, inhibit `CWinApp::OnIdle()` which is need for the handler
`ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_INDICATOR_STATUS_MACHINE, &CMainFrame::OnUpdateIndicatorStatusMachine)`.

This SendMessage just before is too late too
`AfxGetMainWnd()->PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, WM_IDLEUPDATECMDUI)`;

Comment: Are you really calling `SendMessage()`? You're showing `PostMessage()`. There is a big difference. `SendMessage()` causes the message to get sent immediately to the window procedure whereas `PostMessage()` gets put in the message queue. The Post will get processed after a call to MessageBox. The Send will get processed before MessageBox.

Comment: MessageBoxes run a secondary modal message loop, which does not prevent messages posted to windows from being dispatched and processed, only messages posted to a thread. Raymond Chen's blog has a own series of articles on this topic.

Comment: Same principles apply, when entering other modal loops (e.g. size-move operations, or opening a menu). It is at that point where it becomes obvious, that `OnIdle` is really just a best-effort implementation. It relies on a very specific message loop dispatching messages, and that cannot be enforced.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I didn' exactly understand. Con you provide the link from Raymond Chen.

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson I have tried with both (Post&Send) of course.

Comment: @TomTom start with https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050426-18/?p=35783

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SendMessage` with `WM_SETMESSAGESTRING` to your frame window.

See [TN024](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/mfc/tn024-mfc-defined-messages-and-resources?view=msvc-160) for the description.

To update all other indicators or UI components you can use:

```
SendMessageToDescendants(WM_IDLEUPDATECMDUI, TRUE, 0, TRUE, TRUE);
```

on you frame window. Or just directly update the status bar.

```
m_wndStatusBar.OnUpdateCmdUI(m_pMainFrame, TRUE);
```

I would prefer `SendMessageToDescendants`.

Comment: This works only for the first ID_SEPARATOR Indicators, not in the other indicators in the m_wndStatusBar. Right?

Comment: See changed answer.

Comment: For the other `WM_SETMESSAGESTRING`: I am not yet sure about the correct parameters for `SendMessage(..).`  Use `SendMessage(WM_SETMESSAGESTRING, 0, 0)` or `SendMessage(WM_COMMAND, WM_SETMESSAGESTRING, 0)` to route the command the MFC way view->frame->doc.?

Comment: WM_SETMESSAGESTRING is not a WM_COMMAND. You must use it as the message id.
Read TN024

Answer (score 2):

As you have noticed, the UI Update Mechanism is activated just when the application is about to enter the idle state, and it doesn't work when a message-box or modal dialog is displayed. One possible solution could be to call the `SetPaneText()` or `SetPaneStyle()` members of the status-bar yourself. This is not the "recommended" method (the documentation says use the `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` mechanism), but it doesn't work otherwise, plus it is still compatible with it, as it will be working normally as soon as the message-box or the modal dialog is closed.

So, the code could be like:

```
UINT nStyle = m_wndStatusBar.GetPaneStyle(ID_INDICATOR_STATUS_MACHINE);
m_wndStatusBar.SetPaneStyle(ID_INDICATOR_STATUS_MACHINE, bEnable? nStyle & ~SBPS_DISABLED : nStyle | SBPS_DISABLED);
```

If you need to call these from a part of code outside the CMainFrame class, you can make them a public function of the `CMainFrame` class, or make the `m_wndStatusBar` public, so you can call, for example:

```
((CMainFrame*)AfxGetMainWnd())->EnableStatusMachineIndicator(bEnable);
```

or

```
UINT nStyle = ((CMainFrame*)AfxGetMainWnd())->m_wndStatusBar.GetPaneStyle(ID_INDICATOR_STATUS_MACHINE);
.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this: to map a custom message handler for your statusbar in your CMainFrame:

```
// header
afx_msg LRESULT OnMyUpdateSB(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

and implementation:

```
ON_MESSAGE(WMU_MYUPDATESB, &CMainFrame::OnMyUpdateSB)

LRESULT CMainFrame::OnMyUpdateSB(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // call OnUpdateIndicatorStatusMachine code

    return 1;
}
```

and just before call (Afx)MessageBox, send a PostMessage to CMainFrame:

```
::PostMessage(AfxGetMainWnd()->GetSafeHwnd(), WMU_MYUPDATESB, 0, 0);
```

Or, how **xMRi** said, you can send a `WM_SETMESSAGESTRING` as a `PostMessage`, or, better (if works) `SendMessage`.

Comment: Question: What is the advantage of a custom message handler in favor of a public Method in CMainFrame. ex `void CMainFrame: void UpdateMySB(CString& strText)`

Comment: No advantage of using a custom message handler instead of using a standard message, ex `WM_SETMESSAGESTRING`, the difference between a message or a public method is that you can call messages (custom or not) with PostMessage (asynchronous). [Didn't come in my mind `WM_SETMESSAGESTRING` when I wrote the post.]